# How do I get php to simulate a visit to a url?

Tags: php, automation

I set up a crontab to execute a php file every minute.
Now I need to create the php file but I’m clueless on what the contents should be.

All the code needs to do is visit the website url.
No need to save anything.
It just needs mimic loading the home page just like a browser would.
That in turn triggers a chain of events which are already in place.
It is an extremely low traffic site so that’s the reason for it.

I know, I could do it with curl.
But for reasons I won’t get into, it needs to be a php file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please. Not expecting you to provide code, just direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use curl in PHP to just send a request to the page:

```
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "the.url-of-the-page.here");
curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

- [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)
- [Example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it with one line (note that the whole HTML of the page is retrieved which takes a bit longer):

```
file_get_contents('URL');
```

As [Prince Dorcis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14066311/prince-dorcis) stated you could also use curl. If the website is not yours you should maybe (or have to) use curl and send a request with a useragent (you can find a list [here](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/)):

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

Answer (score 1):

Marco M is right, but there is a catch (it may not be for most but there is sometimes)

```
file_get_contents("https://example.com");
```

normally does the trick (i use that more than i should) BUT !
There is a setting in php.ini that needs to be on for that function to enable it to open URLs !
I had that once with a webhoster, they did not allow that ;)